# How does fzf manage stdin?

Tags: terminal, posix, stdin, pty, fzf

`fzf` fuzzily searches for a *needle* in a *haystack*.
Consider the following snippet:

```sh
(sleep 5 && printf "this is some\ninput") | fzf
```

During the `sleep`, I'm still able to type things to `fzf`, and it understands them as the *needle*.

The piped input is correctly segregated, and `fzf` understand it as the *haystack*.

**How does `fzf` tell the difference between the two?**
Is there somewhere simple in the [source code](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) I can look for clarity?
Does this have anything to do with the *alternate screen*, which I think `fzf` is using?

Context here is a personally instructive re-implementation of fzf in python. Rough WIP is [here](https://github.com/aatifsyed/rich-elm/blob/4ddb0011b5cf6540ae5240418c736ec8489188d5/rich_elm/__main__.py).